# Why is the e in the LHS equals to cos + isin in the RHS?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

**In the Method 1 and 2 how is the $e$ in the LHS equal to the RHS?**

In the junior classes I was just given to learn that $cos(\frac{π}{2}±\theta)=\mp sin\theta$ but we never proved it.

I have no idea how the e got there in the first statement of the proof.

Can anyone prove the first statement of the proof of Method 1 and 2?

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: how the $e$ got there:  $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin x$ is [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin x$ is [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Also, $\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2\pm\theta\right)=\mp \sin\theta$ follows from the angle addition formula

$\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2\pm\theta\right)=\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)\cos(\theta)\mp\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2\right)\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Euler's formula could be proved using power series